# How does a Tasktracker obtain it's necessary data

Tags: hadoop

I have a data science background, so my goal of using Hadoop would be to store large amounts of data in a `HDFS` and use a cluster to perform some (parallelized) analytics (e.g. some Machine learning algorithms) on parts of these datasets. To be a little bit more specific, consider the following case: for some large dataset stored in a `HDFS`, I want to run a simple algorithm on, say, 100 random samples of this dataset and combine these results.

As I understand the concept, to achieve this, I could write a `Map` function that tells the `Tasktrackers` on my cluster nodes to perform the analytic on part of the data. Moreover, I should write a `Reduce` function to 'combine' the results.

Now for the technical side; as I understood, each of the machines in my cluster contains a `DataNode` and a `TaskTracker`. I imagine that a `TaskTracker` on a certain machine might require data for its calculations, that is not present on the `DataNode` on this particular machine. So the main question that arises is: How does a `TaskTracker` obtain its required data? Does it combine data present on its neighboring `DataNode` with data from other `DataNodes`, or does it treat its neighbor `DataNode` as equally as all the other `DataNodes` in the cluster? Is all required data transferred to a `TaskTracker` in the first place?

Please shed some light on these questions as it would really help me in understanding the fundamental principles of Hadoop. Should I have completely have misunderstood the Hadoop workflow in the first place, please let me know, as it, too, would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if data is not present on DataNode,
then as per hadoop it can ask to NameNode and it will get the list of nodes which holds the blocks of data and DataNode will copy that data from respective DataNodes.

Please have a look at the links and image which might help to you to understand flow in HDFS and Hadoop system.

[image: hadoop-flow]

The below link is having a very good explanation of the flow.
I hope it will help.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-zw6KHOtbT4MmRkZWJjYzEtYjI3Ni00NTFjLWE0OGItYTU5OGMxYjc0N2M1/view?pli=1

Comment: Indeed want to refer to 'DataNode'.
The answer is very helpful. In short: if necessary for a certain 'TaskTracker' the required data is moved to the corresponding 'DataNode', right?

Comment: Please check the links, it will give you idea regarding the flow.

Comment: Usually, based on number of input splits, number of mappers are spawned hence, the mapping task is given to tasktracker which is having particular block as its local block, in case if the data is not present, then it will be transferred.